# Closure, denseness in Zariski Topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

This question is from my assignment in algebraic geometry and I am struck on it.

Question: Let X =Spec A be the prime spectrum ( with Zariski Topology) of a ring A.

(a) Prove that for every $x\in X$ , the closure of x = {$y\in X| $ $p_x\subseteq p_y$}

Attempt:  A point $x\in X$ is a prime ideal in A and is denoted by  $p_x$. Closure of x = x $\cup $ all limit points of x. I think all the limit points of X are x only as x is a singleton set. So, I don't have any idea on how I can prove the assertion given in the statement. Can you please give a hint as I think there is something wrong with the way I am trying to attempt the question?

(b) A point $x\in X$ is closed iff the prime ideal $p_x$ corresponding to x is a maximal ideal in A.

Let x is closed and $p_x$ is not maximal ideal but a prime ideal. I don't know   which result to
use to derive a contradiction?

Let on the converse , the prime ideal $p_x$  corresponding to x is a maximal ideal in A, then x not be a closed set, again I am not sure what result to use to prove what is asked.

> I would like to say that I haven't used any property of Zariski topology till now. I understand properties of Zariski topology but I am not sure what exact property I can use it here.

(c)  Spm A is dense in Spec A iff $N_A = M_A$, where $N_A$ and $M_A$ denote the nil -radical and Jacobson radical ideal of A.

Again, In this part I am not sure how can I proceed in any of the direction.

Kindly just give some hints only. I would like to complete the solution by myself.

Thanks!

Comment: Use the closed susbsets in the Zariski topolgy are all of the form $\{x|I\subset p_x\}$ for some ideal $I$ of $A$.

Comment: @Justauser Can you elaborate by writing an answer? I have shown my attempt in question and question has 3 parts.It's not clear for what part your comment is useful?